# Get in a Json child with a String

Tags: json, swift, string

I wan't to get the value of a String called `symbolString`. I don't know how to do this. This is what i got so far. I tried first to get in the Data child and then go to the `symbolString` to get the ImageUrl Value. It doesn't seem to work. Please help!

```
final let urlString = "https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/"

        func downloadJsonWithURL() {
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
                if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                    if let DataArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Data") as? NSArray {
                        print(DataArray)
                        for Data in DataArray{
                            if let DataDict = Data as? NSDictionary {
                                if let nameURL = DataDict.value(forKey: "\(self.symbolString)") as? NSDictionary {
                                    if let name = nameURL.value(forKey: "ImageUrl") {
                                        self.imageString.append(name as! String)
                                        print(self.imageString)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
        }
```

Comment: There is no array (`[]`) in the JSON. All collection types are dictionary (`{}`). By the way, variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter and don't use `NSArray, NSDictionary` and `valueForKey` in Swift

Comment: There does not seem to by any instance of `symbolString` in your data. Where exactly do you expect to find it?

Comment: symbolString is a string that is for example " BTC". That works, I have checked it. But if you look at the url I first need to get in the "Data" and than for example "BTC" (symbolString). But i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code. Its working for me.

```
 func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url = "https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/"
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in

        guard let unwrappedDAta = data else {
            print("Error unwrapping data")
            return
        }

        do {
            let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedDAta, options: []) as? NSDictionary

            if let dataDict = responseJSON!["Data"] as? NSDictionary {
                for (key, _) in dataDict {
                    if let keyDict = dataDict[key] as? NSDictionary {
                        if let imageURL = keyDict["ImageUrl"] as? String {
                            self.imageString.append(imageURL)
                        }
                        print(self.imageString)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Could not get API data. \(error))")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```